# Problems seeing CSS and JS in GitHub Pages, but working well in VS Code

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

I am working in a page for a project and I used a template that included CSS and JS files. I worked the code in Visual Studio Code and it worked well locally in my computer. I used GitHub Pages in order to share it but there are elements missng like the button to show/hide the menu, the background, and arrows.

Here is my repository https://github.com/azu-any/reafo.git

This is how it should look:
[Using VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWNe3.png)

And how it looks using GitHub:
[GitHub Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPfuM.png)

Thanks in advance!

PS. I've already checked the url's and they work fine, otherwise other styles would not function.

Answer (score 1):

Files with names starting with underscore, like `_styles_js.js` [are blocked in GitHub Pages](https://gitlab.com/antora/antora/-/issues/194).

You have two options:

1. Create an empty `.nojekyll` file in the root of your repository
2. Get rid of `_` prefix from filenames

Comment: That also applies to directories starting with `_`, like `_next/static/...`. Anyway thanks, I solved issue with your answer.